# Google Chrome Extension:Call Python function from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension and from my javascript file, I am getting the `url` of the active tab. Now I want to pass this `url` to my python function in python code. How can I achieve this. I have tried few solutions posted here, but its no help. I need to send the "myurl" in the below code to my python function and get back results too.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var myurl = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(myurl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might works

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("python.exe", "file.py");
```